# DataTable rows.every function Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am creating an attendance tracker with the jQuery DataTables plugin! I have gotten really far with the functionality/capability and have just been stuck for weeks trying to figure out how to do this last portion of what I want it to do.

I will have a static/workable test case attached below. So the issue that I cannot figure out is how to style the parent rows based off of the child row cell values. The columns Sunday-Friday are colored based off of a hidden value called SundayStatus, MondayStatus, TuesdayStatus, and so on. There are two values that could cause it to turn green (TW & P), two values that could cause it to turn yellow (NR & O), and two values to cause it to turn red (PTO & H). In my `rows.every(function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {` function I need to find a way to manipulate the data and add classes to the parent rows based off the attendance values from each individual day.

P.S.(I created my own plugin `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function` to search through all of the data in the table and only show items where the dates Sunday-Friday are dates that are in the current week.

***UPDATE 5/10*** Andrew was on the right track with the update to his answer, I made one small change to today format, and changed `var result = Object.keys(data).find(key => data[key].substring(0,10) === today);` to `var result = Object.keys(data).find(key => typeof data[key] === 'string' && data[key].startsWith(today));`. I then created a conditional in my dynamic code, to read through the result from the reverse-lookup and depending on what the result is, to color the row a certain color.

Here is my JSFiddle of the Static Example that was previously in a snippet within the post: https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/y8t0xoze/19/

In this update, my last and final issue that I am dealing with that I did not foresee, is that everything seems to be working fine, but it appends the status class from the first item that is posted to the DataTable and doesn't take into account for the other items. I have hit a mental block trying to figure out a way around this issue, but here is my rows.every function from my dynamic application which is inside of my startRender function

```
var statusClass = '';
                    rows.every(function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
                    var data = this.data();

                    var node = this.node();

                    var today = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"); // "05/10/2021"
                    console.log(today);
                    
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

                    var result = Object.keys(data).find(key => typeof data[key] === 'string' && data[key].startsWith(today)); // "Monday"
                    console.log(result);

                    var todayStatus = result ? data[result + 'Status'] : 'n/a'; 
                    console.log(todayStatus);
                    
                        if(todayStatus === "P" || todayStatus === "TW") {
                            statusClass = 'green';
                        }
                        if(todayStatus === "NR" || todayStatus === "O") {
                            statusClass = 'yellow';
                        }
                        if (todayStatus === "PTO" || todayStatus === "H") {
                            statusClass = 'red';
                        }
                    });
                    //Add category name to the <tr>.   
                        return $('<tr/>').addClass(statusClass)
                        .append('<td colspan="8">' + group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</td>')
                        .attr('data-name', all)
                        .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks very close, to me!

Here are some changes I recommend:

1. After the end of your closing `</table>` tag, there is an extra `<body>` tag. That looks incorrect - it should be removed. I don't think this causes any errors - but it is worth fixing.
2. In your `rows.every()` function, the `data` variable is a plain array - for example:

   [ "IT", "Name 1", "Locations Here", "05/02/2021", "05/03/2021", "P", … ]

Therefore you cannot use `data.MondayStatus` - because that will be `undefined`. Instead use something like `data[5]` to get the 6th item in the array (`P`).

3. If you want to change the background color of a row for a location (e.g. "IT" or "OM"), you can use a selector like this:

   $("tr[data-name='IT'] td").addClass("green");

This works because you have already added a custom attribute called `data-name` to the relevant `<td>` tag. The selector finds the `<td>` tag which is the child of the `<tr>` tag using that custom attribute.

However, the problem here is: You are trying to assign the class to a table node *before* the DataTable has finished being built.

To address this you can move all of that row looping logic to an `initComplete` function:

```js
initComplete: function(settings, json) {
  this.api().rows().every(function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
    var data = this.data();
    var node = this.node().previousSibling; // to handle your row grouping
    if (node !== null) {
      if (data[5] === "P") {
        var selectorVar = "[data-name='" + data[0] + "'] td";                       
        $( selectorVar ).addClass("green");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Instead of `if (data[5] === "P")`, you can expand this logic to handle different values and also different class names (not just "green"), for whatever the overall logic is that you need. My logic is just a small demo to show the color change.

---

**Update to handle "today"**

To show the approach, let's assume the following record:

```js
var data = {  
  "Department": "IT",
  "Name": "Name 1",
  "Locations": "Locations Here",
  "Sunday": "2021-05-09",
  "Monday": "2021-05-10",
  "MondayStatus": "P",
  "Tuesday": "2021-05-11",
  "TuesdayStatus": "Q",
  "Wednesday": "2021-05-12",
  "WednesdayStatus": "R",
  "Thursday": "2021-05-13",
  "ThursdayStatus": "S",
  "Friday": "2021-05-14",
  "FridayStatus": "T"
};
```

This `data` variable is what I think you are handling in the `rows.every` function. So, it's the equivalent of `var data = this.data();`. I may have got some of the keys wrong (uppercase/lowercase) - but you can adjust the test data if that is the case.

Now, I get today's date, formatted to match the same format as the dates in the `data` object:

```js
var today = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"); // "2021-05-10"
```

I use this value to find the equivalent value in the `data` variable, and I return the key name for that entry:

```js
var result = Object.keys(data).find(key => data[key].substring(0,10) === today); // "Monday"
```

This is basically a reverse-lookup from what you would normally do. Instead of starting with a key, we start with a value and end with a key - in this case, the key is the string "Friday".

Now we take this string and append "Status" to it.

This gives us an actual key string: "FridayStatus".

Now we use that key to find the status for today (if it exists at all in the `data` object):

```js
var todayStatus = result ? data[result + 'Status'] : 'n/a'; // "P"
```

If the date does not exist, then you will end up with a status of "n/a".

Overall, this gives us a quick way to get today's status, without having to perform lots of if/else logic.

Once you have today's status you can use it in a smaller if/else to choose the required color you want to apply to the row.

Comment: I used .MondayStatus as my actual application is using object data which is received through an ajax call

Comment: Understood. In that case, my point (2) is irrelevant. And I'm sure you have already adjusted point (3) accordingly.

Comment: see my most recent edit, I think I got it with the ```rows.every(function```, now I just need to read through the data rows and only update the top parent row based off of the currDay value being = to whatever value it may be

Comment: OK - so, rather than try to edit your code (and break something) I have, instead, provided some stand-alone code showing you one approach (assuming I understood what you are looking to do). If that approach is helpful, you can incorporate it into your `rows.every` processing.

Comment: Thank you! Although when I try to log the result and todayStatus, I get this logged in console: ```5/10/2021 undefined n/a```

Comment: Right - because now, today is Monday 10th May. When I wrote my code, it was Friday 7th May. My test data in `var data = { ... }` does not contain a date for 10th May anywhere. You wanted the code to be "date aware", right? So, you can edit my test data.

Comment: When I look at my object data in my dynamic example with fetch, I was searching for the keys and what should have popped up. For example since today is Monday that should be the expected key to == result. In the response, the date is being stored in ISO String "2021-05-10T04:00:00Z" and is later being formatted when populated to the table. Could this have anything to do with the reverse lookup?

Comment: Are you saying that the data you are actually using is not the same format as the data in the question? The question uses dates in the format "2021-05-10". Is that not the actual format of the real data?

Comment: it is formatted "2021-05-10" when it is populated to the datatable I render it like so `{ "data": "Monday",
                render: function(data, type, row){
                if(type === "sort" || type === "type"){
                    return data;
                }
                return moment(data).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
            }
            },` and in the results, it is stored as so Monday: "2021-05-10T04:00:00Z"

Comment: OK - that was my mistake - sorry about that. I have updated the final section of my answer, based on the assumption that the dates are all in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` when they are stored in the DataTable.

Comment: so I fixed it, but check out my newest update if you have a chance

Comment: Happy to help, but I am not sure what this means: _"the first item that is posted to the DataTable"_. (Also, can't you reduce those 15 `if` statements to only 3 `if` statements? Do you need all those `result === "Monday"`, `result === "Tuesday"`... statements?)

Comment: I truly feel like an idiot haha, I updated my conditional to only include three if statements.  This is what you were referring to correct? I will get a scrreenshot of what I am talking about

Comment: Yes - those 3 `if` statements are what I was referring to. I am not sure if that resolved your final issue, or not.

Comment: it actually appears the top group is styled by the rows with the most common color applied to them? If there are 3 green and 2 red, it will style it green. Vice versa

Comment: Running a bunch of possible different combinations of different results through to make sure it is actually doing that

Comment: Sorry, I am mot sure what that means. I think the code in your Fiddle may be out-of-date, at this point. What does your latest code look like?